# How can I learn to create beautiful infographics (with connection to my R knowledge)?

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization

I am a devoted R (r-project.org) user, and love infographics.

I just came across this article:
http://www.noupe.com/design/fantastic-information-architecture-resources.html

Giving a long list of resources for information designers.

And it raised in me the desire to do more beautiful (not just informative) R plots.

Do you have any suggestion/resources on how to make this leap?

What books/software/skills do I need to have/develop in order to be able to make beautiful infographics?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here's a list of resources that I would suggest:

Tufte's books are really excellent, although my favorite is actually his second book: [Envisioning Information](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_ei).  Separately, I always found the [periodic table of visualization methods](http://www.visual-literacy.org/periodic_table/periodic_table.html) to be entertaining.  Ross Ihaka also [taught a course on this subject](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Eihaka/courses/120/) in the past.

For R, learn [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/). The [learnr.wordpress.com](http://learnr.wordpress.com/) blog is an excellent resource for this.  You might consider [the ggplot book](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/book/) and [the original Grammar of Graphics book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387987746).

Here's another useful article from the same site that you linked in your question: [Data Visualization: Modern Approaches](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/08/02/data-visualization-modern-approaches/).

Some good blogs on the subject:

- http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/
- http://flowingdata.com/

In some cases, you might want to do your data manipulation in R, but create the visualization with another tool (see, for instance, [this list](http://www.insideria.com/2009/12/28-rich-data-visualization-too.html)).  Here are some of the best tools that I have found over the years:

- [Processing](http://www.processing.org/)
- [Prefuse](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse)
- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)

Lastly, an interesting open visualization platform was [many eyes](http://www.bewitched.com/manyeyes.html).

Comment: Totally starred.  Rocking answer!

Comment: Which tool would you recommend for someone intending to create batches of infographics? I have to generate monthly reports for 70 corporate branches and can't find the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 13):

You might want to look into using R to create your underlying graphics, and then saving them in an editable format (like [svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)).  Then using a more art focused application to edit your svg to make it beautifull (like [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/)).  See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048304/create-editable-plots-from-r) for an example using [Cairo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/index.html).  I'd also +1 the learn ggplot2 from Shane.

Comment: Thank you Paul, that is most useful!

Answer (score 7):

If the R side of your skills is pretty good, then you'll definitely want to start reading **[Edward Tufte](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/)**'s books, particularly **[The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0961392142)** and **[Beautiful Evidence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0961392177)**, both of which provide excellent insights into how to present data effectively and efficiently.

You should be somewhat forewarned that everyone has a different idea of "beautiful," however. Tufte is a big believer in maximizing a quantity he calls the "data-ink ratio": how much of the page's ink is dedicated to data instead of what he calls "chartjunk". This causes his work to have a sleek, minimalist oeuvre that certainly makes it easier to digest everything but that some people may find too utilitarian. But for Tufte, function and form are pretty close to one thing: the more it helps you, the more beautiful and elegant it is.

Answer (score 1):

The [`tikz` manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) contains a few dozen pages on how to make good graphics (using `tikz`). So it's not entirely specific to R, but the ideas are interesting and worked out with examples.

I don't know what's the ultimate goal of your visualizations, but if LaTeX is involved (and when is it not involved for beautiful typography? ;)) it can be a good idea to rework your graphics in a vector graphics language, as Shane suggested.

Answer (score -4):

I am using Tableau Public, it is free software to create charts and maps. Charts are not stunning but I like maps, I do not know better free software for info maps creation.

Comment: Not an answer for the question

Answer (score -5):

a good option is to make your own flash components for visual studio and work with they in asp.net