# Redirecting R graphs to MS Word

Tags: r

I wonder how to redirect R graphs to MS Word? Like `sink()` redirect the R output to any file but not the graphs. I tried R2Wd but sometimes it doesn't work properly. Any comment and help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I usually save the plots to files in formats such as jpeg (`jpeg()`) and PDF (`pdf()`), among others.  Can you clarify what doesn't work about R2Wd?

Comment: R2wd sometimes got stuck with ggplot2. Saving only few graphs as jpeg or PDF is fine but very difficult if have many graphs in the report.

Comment: If you are having specific problems with R2wd ("got stuck" is almost as vague as "sometimes it doesn't work properly", although you have at least narrowed down the problem to `ggplot2`), you should consider (a) contacting the package maintainers (try `maintainer("R2Wd")`) and (b) setting up a reproducible example (which you could include in a edited version of this question ...)  Are you aware of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your direct question, the best way to get the results of R scripts and plots into word is probably via some form of [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/).  Look up [odfweave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html) to send R output to a [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) file that can then be converted to word, or even opened directly in Word if you have the right plugin.

To create plots that can be editable (i.e you can alter the look of plots, move the legend etc) I would recommend saving the plot to an svg format (scalable vector graphic) that you can then edit using the excellent free vector graphics app [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

For instance, if I create my ggplot2 graph as an object

```
library(ggplot2)
dataframe<-data.frame(fac=factor(c(1:4)),data1=rnorm(400,100,sd=15))
dataframe$data2<-dataframe$data1*c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1)
testplot<-qplot(x=fac, y=data2,data=dataframe, colour=fac, geom=c("boxplot", "jitter"))
```

You can use the Cairo package, which allows creation of svg files, I can then edit these in Inkscape.

```
library(Cairo)
Cairo(600,600,file="testplot.svg",type="svg",bg="transparent",pointsize=8, units="px",dpi=400)
testplot
dev.off()
Cairo(1200,1200,file="testplot12200.png",type="png",bg="transparent",pointsize=12, units="px",dpi=200)
testplot
dev.off()
```

For more info read this previous question that has more good answers [Create Editable plots from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048304/create-editable-plots-from-r)

Also, you can follow this advice from Hadley, and save the actual ggplot2 object, then load it later and modify it

```
save(testplot, file = "test-plot.rdata")
# Time passes and you start a new R session
load("test-plot.rdata")
testplot + opts(legend.position = "none")
testplot + geom_point()
```

Comment: Note that the current version of `odfWeave` is not working with the current version of the `XML` package (3.4-2) -- you'll need to downgrade (to 3.2, I think)

Comment: @Ben Bolker : Prof. Frank Harrell put some information regarding TtH on this website http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/SweaveConvert. I'd appreciate if you explain this for Windows. Thanks

Comment: I don't know exactly what there is to explain "for Windows". `tth` is available for windows: http://hutchinson.belmont.ma.us/tth/tth-noncom/download.html ... (do also note that Harrell recommends starting with `htlatex` (rather than `tth`) as the current "best practice" for converting LaTeX to Word

Comment: @Ben Bolker : Thanks for your comments and pointing out htlatex.

Answer (score 2):

To get sink() like behavior with MSword look at the `wdTxtStart` function in the `TeachingDemos` package.  This uses R2wd internally, so you will see similar functionality, this just sends everything you do to the word document.

Graphs are not sent automatically since you may be adding to them, but once you know you are finished with the graph you can use `wdtxtPlot` to send the current graph to the word document.

If you know what you want to do ahead of time then `sweave` or something similar is probably the better approach (as has already been mentioned).  The group that created Rexcel are also working on Sword that does sweave like things within MSword.