# R, export a file to keynote

Tags: file, r, export, vector-graphics, keynote

Is there a way to export a graph made in R in a way that keynote can read the objects of the graph as separate objects and not like a single image?

Usually I export graphs in R as pdf but then Keynote import them as a single object.

Comment: How about exporting graphs in separate files, and then read each file in Keynote?

Comment: I think not in the way you wish. An R graph can be only exported in (vector/raster) image, which cannot be altered in keynote/powerpoint etc.

Comment: try exporting in svg and converting it to keynote shapes http://www.christianholz.net/svg2keynote_svg_to_keynote.html

Comment: @baptiste, why don't you make your comment an answer?

Comment: svg2keynote didn't work for me (all the plot elements come out as black-filled boxes) using either grDevices::svg() or ggsave(). I've got the '08 release of Keynote, so that might be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments: try exporting in svg and converting it to keynote shapes. Several tools exist, for instance http://christianholz.net/svg2keynote_svg_to_keynote.html (or through illustrator) and http://mcb.berkeley.edu/labs/zusman/dave/svg2key/

Note: I have not been able to test this idea successfully, they seem to depend on the version of OSX/Keynote)

Comment: To convert the svg to keynote I used Eazydraw.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you;

a) Want to put one object into another application, and edit it, In which case, try saving it as an svg object that can then be edited in a suitable application like Inkscape (see [Create Editable plots from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048304/create-editable-plots-from-r/2049391#2049391))

b) Want to create a series of objects and then put them into another application individually, in which case I would either i. use at Sweave which can create a pdf document, but will also create an individual pdf/eps file for each object or ii. Look at odfweave which works like sweave but can create an OpenDocument .odt that could be opened in LibreOffice.