# R, ggplot2, introducing the elements of a graph sequentially during a keynote presentation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use ggplot2 to plot my graphs. I want to use the graphs to create a keynote presentation.

During my presentation, I want to introduce different elements of the plot sequentially. First, the points corresponding to the condition A, then the points corresponding to condition B and then some curves for example.

I thought that maybe I could create the whole plot and export it in a way that I could manipulate single elements in keynote (like deleting the points of one condition). Thanks to people from stackoverflow, I was able to do that:
[R, export a file to keynote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693707/r-export-a-file-to-keynote)

But I found that it is very difficult to select individual elements in keynote. So, I wonder which is there is some more efficient way.

Comment: I suppose making a separate image corresponding to each additional plot element and then just displaying them on a series of slides isn't 'more efficient', but it's an option at least.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're willing to use some different tools, this is very doable with `Sweave` and the `LaTeX` document class `beamer` for the slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Sequential Graphs}
\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{
Here's a graph:
<<echo = FALSE,fig = TRUE>>=
library(ggplot2)
d1 <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = runif(20),grp = rep(letters[1:2],each = 10))
p <- ggplot(data = d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
print(p)
@
}

\frame{
Here's the next graph:
<<echo = FALSE,fig = TRUE>>=
p <- p +geom_line(aes(group = 1))
print(p)
@
}

\frame{
Here's the last graph:
<<echo = FALSE,fig = TRUE>>=
p <- p +geom_point(aes(colour = grp))
print(p)
@
}
\end{document}
```

I've used `ggplot` here since it has a convenient syntax for adding elements to a graph, but this should work with any other graphics method in R, I'd think.

Comment: +1 I agree with this general approach, i.e. create separate plots and save these to disk.  Using beamer isn't essential.  This code will generate a pdf for each plot.  These pdf files can then be individually imported into a presentation to 'build' the plot.